# Does descriptor indexing PARTIALLY_BOUND_BIT obviate the need for nullDescriptor feature

Tags: vulkan

I have had debug validation layer errors logged when I set certain image_views/samplers/buffers to VK_NULL_HANDLE, representing that there was no texture/whatever there at that binding (or array element) of the descriptor set. When I did this I got errors saying that if a descriptor is null then a feature needs to be enabled called nullDescriptor feature.

I haven't been able to find anything about this feature and I'd be grateful if someone showed me a link to the docs for this?

However if I enable the descriptor indexing extension, and the descriptor indexing feature "descriptorBindingPartiallyBound", and set the descriptor with the descriptor binding flag VK_DESCRIPTOR_BINDING_PARTIALLY_BOUND_BIT, then I imagine that whether a particular descriptor is null or nonsense/junk/nonsensical shouldn't matter. What you're saying essentially is "I'm not going to access that descriptor in my shaders", so it shouldn't matter whether it's null or not, and so the nullDescriptor feature isn't needed. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I imagine that whether a particular descriptor is null or nonsense/junk/nonsensical shouldn't matter.

The API still doesn't let you do it. You cannot set a descriptor to an "invalid" value. You can only set it to a valid one. You can *cause* it to become invalid, but at no point can you set it to such a value.

If you can set a descriptor to a value, there must be some idea of what that means. The nullDescriptor feature, part of the VK_EXT_robustness2 extension, gives meaning to what happens if you access a null descriptor.

So there is no way to explicitly choose to tell Vulkan that a desctiptor is invalid. Just don't use it.

Comment: So set it to anything but VK_NULL_HANDLE. Assuming I don't access it does it matter what that value is?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Don't set it to anything. If you set it to something, that "something" has to be legitimate at the time it is set. It can later become invalid, but it must have been valid at some point.

Comment: So you can't "write" null/junk/nonsense values to a descriptor, but partially bound descriptor feature allows for you only to write certain descriptors, meaning the ones that haven't been written to are undefined/junk, but that's all right as long as you don't "write" invalid/junk values?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Yes, that's the idea: you only write to a descriptor you are trying to actually use. If you're not using it, you don't write to it.

Comment: Have you written a renderer where you have a massive descriptor array of images for sampling, to be indexed in the shader? That's what I've got, I want all of the images in loaded by the engine in this array. Some of the elements in the array have nothing in it. Do I have to write them all with a dummy image view value? I can't write null and they all have to be valid.

Comment: @Zebrafish: I don't really understand the problem. Just put them there. If there's no image in an array slot, don't put anything in that array slot. Yes, you're probably going to have a lot of `VkWriteDescriptorSet`s in your initial update call. But after that, you only updating elements that have *changed* since the last time they were updated.